# Sum of reciprocal quadratic

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Is there a general method or formula for calculating the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(an^{2}+bn+c) $?

Comment: There's a nice discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322086/series-of-reciprocals-of-a-quadratic-polynomial

Comment: Anyway the question is not solved at that MathSE link. Yet it would be useful to mention what it says.

Comment: The Stackeschange answer does not solve the problem, and it is so non-trivial that it could well be asked on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

It depends what you call "calculating". If you want the result in "closed form",
any series of rational functions of $n$ can be summed in terms of the logarithmic
derivative $\psi$ of the gamma function and its derivatives, simply by decomposing
into partial fractions. If you want a numerical approximation, you can either use
this, or the many summation methods existing in the literature which can give you
thousands of decimals in fractions of a second.